# Гонка потоков при использовании schedule с разными потоками

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, schedule

В одном из своих проектов заметил проблему с `schedule`:

- У меня есть несколько функций, которые выполняются в отдельных потоках и по расписанию (время разное)
- Но заметил, что одна из функций вызывалась два раза и одновременно

Накидал минимальный пример и проблема подтвердилась. Вызов функций действительно дублируется

Пример:

```
import threading
import time

import schedule


def run1():
    print('run1', threading.current_thread())
    time.sleep(2)


def run2():
    print('run2', threading.current_thread())
    time.sleep(3)


def run_schedule(timeout, run):
    schedule.every(timeout).seconds.do(run)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


threading.Thread(target=run_schedule, args=[5, run1]).start()
threading.Thread(target=run_schedule, args=[7, run2]).start()
```

Вывод:

```
run1 run1 <Thread(Thread-1, started 17828)>
<Thread(Thread-2, started 14008)>
run2 <Thread(Thread-2, started 14008)>
run2 <Thread(Thread-1, started 17828)>
```

Как видно, функции вызываются по одному разу на каждый поток, что вызывает `run_pending`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решением будет создавать отдельные `schedule` для разных потоков.

Достаточно поменять функцию:

```
def run_schedule(timeout, run):
    scheduler = schedule.Scheduler()
    scheduler.every(timeout).seconds.do(run)

    while True:
        scheduler.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

---

**PS.**

Думаю, и выделение отдельного потока для цикла с `schedule.run_pending()` тоже сработало бы, а чтобы функции выполнялись в отдельных потоках нужно бы в `.do(run)` оборачивать код в поток, типа:

```
scheduler.every(timeout).seconds.do(lambda: Thread(target=run).start())
```

Comment: классная штука `multiprocessind.dummy.Pool` -  лучший интерфейс к тредам в питоне.

Comment: @eri, прозвучало как реклама :D Я этот класс только с `map` использовал, но посмотрел и увидел в спеке, что можно в пул добавлять задачи через `pool.apply_async` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), тогда в моем примере добавить создание `pool = Pool()` и `scheduler.every(timeout).seconds.do(lambda: pool.apply_async(run))` или так `scheduler.every(timeout).seconds.do(pool.apply_async, run)`. Но, количество потоков будет небольшое, поэтому можно будет обойтись и `Thread`, но идея с `Pool` мне нравится :)